# Iphone:Loading Limited Records In table View from Sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have more than 100 records in a database of a particular user. Now I want to display only the first 30 from it, and when a "more" button is pressed, 30 more records will appear below them. How can I do it in an iPhone application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Query to achieve your goal

```
-(NSMutableArray *)SelectResult:(int)offset
{

    NSMutableArray *arrdata;
arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3 *database;

NSString *databasePath = [self getDBPath];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSString *sqlQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from TableName where RecordId > %d and RecordId <=%d",offset,offset+30];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    compiledStatement=nil;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlQuery UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            if ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)!=0)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *temData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                int pKey = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement,0);

                [temData setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pKey] forKey:@"RecordId"];
                [arrdata addObject:temData];
            }
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);

return arrdata;
}
```

Please call this method and **pass offset as integer** it will give you 30 recored from the offset

like **offset = 0 then 1 to 30**
     **offset = 30 then 31 to 60** etc....

Hope it will help you

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `NSMutableArray` to hold you data. In your table view `datasource` make sure it displays an extra cell (with the "More" message) if there are any more records to display.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can then modify the table view's data array by adding additional records from the database.

You can generate your SQL query dynamically based on the size of your data array.